# Having trouble maintaining const correctness with parameter passed by reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I'm sure this has been asked before, but all the search results have `const&` questions.

I want to make sure the following method doesn't change the `GuestNode` passed to it, so I wanted to pass `const GuestNode& guest`, but g++ won't let that happen, because I'm assigning the `&guest` to pointers. Why does that happen? And how can I make sure the passed param stays as it was?

```
   void GuestList::Add(GuestNode& guest)
   {
      if ( first == 0 )
      {
         //first guest
         first = &guest;
      }
      else
      {
         //nth guest
         GuestNode *p = first;
         while ( p->next != 0 )
            p = p->next;
         p->next = &guest;
      }
      SetCount(GetCount() + 1);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make `guest` a `const GuestNode&`, then `&guest` is a `const GuestNode*`. That is, it's a pointer to a `const GuestNode`. That makes sense, otherwise you'd be able to modify the `const` object through the non-`const` pointer to it. So if you're going to assign that pointer to `first` and/or `p`, you need to make sure that they are `const GuestNode*`s too.

If you need `first`, which I'm assuming is a member of `GuestList`, to be non-`const`, then you shouldn't be taking a `const` reference.

To demonstrate:

```
const int x = 5;
int* p = &x; // error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’
```

Imagine if this weren't an error, I'd then be able to do `*p = 10;` to change the value of `x`, even though the object is supposed to be `const`.

Comment: I understand. But if I make first const, then what do I do, when I need to erase the first element in the list, and adjust the first pointer accordingly?

Comment: @Innkeeper You can still modify the *pointer*. It's just the object it points to that is `const`.

Comment: All right, but still, in this example, if I change `first` to `const`, I need to also do it with `p`, and then, the `p->next = &guest` part won't compile.

Comment: @Innkeeper Exactly, so I guess you don't really want it to be `const`. :D By making it `const`, you would be telling the client that you promise not to do anything to that object. But then you'd be breaking that promise by keeping a non-`const` pointer to it.

Comment: I feel like there should be another solution here... The `GuestNode` im passing surely won't be changed, but because I want to change another `GuestNode`'s `next` pointer, I can't guarantee that the new one cannot be changed?

Comment: @Innkeeper: The problem isn't that you want to change *another* `GuestNode`'s `next` pointer, it's that you plan to eventually change *the new one*'s `next` pointer! (After all, what will happen the next time someone calls this method?) Maybe what you really want is to declare `next` as `mutable`, meaning that it can be modified even on a `const GuestNode`. (This would weaken the definition of what it means to be a `const GuestNode`, making it impossible to declare a `GuestNode` whose `next` never changes.)

Comment: @ruakh Thank you for the clarification. So if this wasn't just a selfmade excercise, what do you think would be the better approach:  
- passing it without `const` as it is right now, and being careful not to change it.  
- declaring `mutable next`  
- some entirely different way of implementing?

Comment: @Innkeeper: I think I'd use a different approach. Instead of having a `GuestNode` class with a `next` pointer, I'd want that sort of detail to be hidden by `GuestList`; so you'd call `GuestList::Add(const Guest &)`, and it would handle all the details of connecting nodes to each other. (I mean, there would still be some sort of node-class, but clients of `GuestList` would not need to be aware of that class at all. It wouldn't appear in the signature of any of `GuestList`'s public methods.)